# Create Eclipse Editor Plugin for a sub set of an extension

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have special kind of .xml files which I need to open through my own eclipse editor. So I added a custom content type and bound with my editor.

This is my Describer class.

```
public class TEPFileContentDescriber implements IContentDescriber {

@Override
public int describe(InputStream contents, IContentDescription description)
        throws IOException {
    try{
        XmlUtil.parseSuite(contents);
        System.out.println("VALID");
        return  IContentDescriber.VALID;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("INVALID");
        return  IContentDescriber.INVALID;
    }
}

@Override
public QualifiedName[] getSupportedOptions() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

In the console I can see the correct status has been triggered, but the Project Explorer still treats all xml files as my type, so the editor complains other files when it tries to open.

1) Is there any other methods I need to Override here?

2) Can I use a separate file icon as well, only for my content type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `describe` method must only return `VALID` if the XML is actually correct for your application.

So in your code `XmlUtil.parseSuite` must throw an exception if the XML is not correct for your app. So, for example, if your describer is given an Ant build script XML you must reject it.

You should also return `INDETERMINATE` if the input looks like XML but is not for your app.

You can extend `XMLContentDescriber` to do some of the work for you.

For example this is the Ant plugin content describer:

```
public final class AntBuildfileContentDescriber extends XMLContentDescriber {
    private int checkCriteria(InputSource contents) throws IOException {
        AntHandler antHandler = new AntHandler();
        try {
            if (!antHandler.parseContents(contents)) {
                return INDETERMINATE;
            }
        }
        catch (SAXException e) {
            // we may be handed any kind of contents... it is normal we fail to parse
            return INDETERMINATE;
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // some bad thing happened - force this describer to be disabled
            String message = "Internal Error: XML parser configuration error during content description for Ant buildfiles"; //$NON-NLS-1$
            throw new RuntimeException(message);
        }
        // Check to see if we matched our criteria.
        if (antHandler.hasRootProjectElement()) {
            if (antHandler.hasProjectDefaultAttribute() || antHandler.hasTargetElement() || antHandler.hasAntElement()) {
                // project and default attribute or project and target element(s)
                // or project and top level ant element(s) (classpath, import, macrodef, path, property, taskdef, typedef)
                return VALID;
            }
            // only a top level project element...maybe an Ant buildfile
            return INDETERMINATE;
        }

        return INDETERMINATE;
    }

    @Override
    public int describe(InputStream contents, IContentDescription description) throws IOException {
        // call the basic XML describer to do basic recognition
        if (super.describe(contents, description) == INVALID) {
            return INVALID;
        }
        // super.describe will have consumed some chars, need to rewind
        contents.reset();
        // Check to see if we matched our criteria.
        return checkCriteria(new InputSource(contents));
    }

    public int describe(Reader contents, IContentDescription description) throws IOException {
        // call the basic XML describer to do basic recognition
        if (super.describe(contents, description) == INVALID) {
            return INVALID;
        }
        // super.describe will have consumed some chars, need to rewind
        contents.reset();
        // Check to see if we matched our criteria.
        return checkCriteria(new InputSource(contents));
    }
}
```

You could use this as a basis and alter `checkCriteria` to do your checks.

Comment: Thanks greg, it automatically get the relevant editors icon as well

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse-editors are **file-base** not **content-based**... you can check your file as described in your answer, but the file type is determinded by the file-ending.

that concept is used in **eclipse** as well as on default file systems like from **windows** or similar...

maybe you should introduce a custom filetype, something like `myfile.tepxml`

you *can* define certain content-types wich are a combination of file name and file extension, but they are customized defined, as a **part of your eclipse setting** and **not part of your editor** (locked are pre-defined from eclipse)

[image]

Comment: i'm pretty sure had had already figured out that you could get along with a different filetype `.tepxml`, sorry for posting the obvious...

Comment: but I have seen some common file extensions open with different editors. ex.plugin.xml, build.properties, web.xml, is it support regex filters?

Comment: If you look through that list of XML content types you will see that several types are bound to *.xml - the content describer selects which one is the correct type

Comment: @greg-449 so, right, you can define, if an editor is suitable for that file - but it does not work the other way round, does it? (i thought that would be the question from the OP)

Comment: Yes it does. The system will ask each content describer if the file is valid and choose the content type and editor to match.

Comment: uhm - i'm a bit puzzled... my files will usually be opened with the editor i choose to use - even if i get a message that the content is not provided? @greg-449

Comment: i surely respect your answer - i'm doing some plugin-dev right now and i really would love to learn these concepts as well!! don't feel threatened! @greg-449

Comment: can you explain these concepts, maybe in a chat? (how can one start a chat in StackOverflow?) @greg-449

Comment: Once you have opened a file Eclipse remembers what you used and continues to use that editor unless you use the 'Open With...' option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103589/discussion-between-martin-frank-and-greg-449).